# How to perform operations on a Dask dataframe and export the results to a csv?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask, dask-dataframe

I have a large input csv file (several GBs) that I import in Dask with a blocksize of 5e6. The input csv contains two columns: "ID" and "Text".

```
ddf1 = dd.read_csv('REL_Input.csv', names=['ID', 'Text'], blocksize=5e6)
```

I need to add a third column to ddf1, "Hash", by parsing the existing "Text" column for a string between "Hash=" and ";". In  Pandas, I can simply do this:

```
ddf1['Hash'] = ddf1['Text'].str.extract(r'Hash=(.*?);')
```

When I do this in Dask, I get an error saying that the "column assignment doesn't support dask.dataframe.core.DataFrame". I tried to use **assign** but had no luck.

I also need to read multiple large csv files (each several GBs in size) from a directory, concatenate them into another Dask dataframe, ddf2. Each of these csv files have 100s of columns but I only need 2: "Hash" and "Name". Here is the code to create ddf2:

```
ddf2 = dd.concat([dd.read_csv(f, usecols=['Hash', 'Name'], blocksize=5e6) for f in glob.glob('*.tsv')], ignore_index=True, axis=0)
```

Then, I need to merge the two dataframes on the "Hash" columns--something like this:

```
ddf3 = ddf1[['ID', 'ddf1_Hash']].merge(ddf2[['ddf2_Hash', 'Name']], left_on='ddf1_Hash', right_on='ddf2_Hash', how='left')
```

Finally, I need to export ddf3 as a csv:

```
df3.to_csv('Output.csv')
```

I looked and it seems I can create the column for ddf1 and perform the merge operation by changing both ddf1 and ddf2 to pandas dfs using **compute**. However, that's not an option for me due to the sheer size of these dataframes. I also tried using the chunks approach in Pandas, but that does not work due to the "out of memory" error.

Is there a good way to tackle this problem? I'm still learning Python so any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I am able to create the third column and merge the two dataframes. Though, now the issue is that I can't export the merged dataframe as a csv.

Answer (score -1):

1. Running regex on a string column. The following snippet uses `assign`:

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

# this step is just to setup a minimum reproducible example
df = pd.DataFrame(list("abcdefghi"), columns=['A'])
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=3)

# this uses assign to extract the relevant content
ddf = ddf.assign(check_c = lambda x: x['A'].str.extract(r'([a-z])'))

# you can see that the computation was done correctly
ddf.compute()
```

2. Concatenating csv files. Do csv files have the same structure/columns? If so, you can just use `dd.read_csv("path_to_csv_files/*csv")`, but if the files have different structures, then your approach is correct:

```py
ddf2 = dd.concat([dd.read_csv(f, usecols=['Hash', 'Name'], blocksize=5e6) for f in glob.glob('*.tsv')], ignore_index=True, axis=0)
```

3. Merging the dataframes. This is going to be an expensive operation, here's a couple of options to potentially reduce the cost of this:

- if any of the dataframes can be put into memory, then it would help to run `.compute()` to get `pandas` dataframe before the merge;
- setting the key variable as `index` on one or both dataframes:

```py
ddf1 = ddf1.set_index('Hash')
ddf2 = ddf2.set_index('Hash')
ddf3 = ddf1.merge(ddf2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

4. Saving `csv`, by default, dask will save each partition to its own csv file, so your path needs to contain an asterisk, e.g.:

```py
df3.to_csv('Output_*.csv', index=False)
```

There are other options possible (explicit paths, custom name function, see https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.to_csv).

If you need a single file, you can use

```py
df3.to_csv('Output.csv', index=False, single_file=True)
```

However, this option is not supported on all systems, so you might want to check that it works using a small sample first (see documentation).

Comment: Thank you. The **assign** snippet helped. However, I am getting out-of-memory error during the ddf3 export to csv:

`ddf3.to_csv('X:/Output/Output-*.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)`

Comment: Hmm, the problem is likely in this step: `ddf3 = ddf1.merge(ddf2, ...)`. Let me update the answer with a possible solution to this.

Comment: Indexing didn't help. In fact, that errored out as well due to memory issues. So the main issue now is that I can't export the merged dataframe.

Comment: Hmmm, is any of the dataframes small enough to fit in memory? if yes, it will help to `.compute` on it before merging. If no, then you could try using smaller partitions, e.g. `ddf3 = ddf3.repartition(npartitions=2*ddf3.npartitions)`. If that doesn't help, then last resort is to operate on subsets of the data.